# How to exclude non-numeric character in regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string which goes like this

```
Section 78(1) of the blabla
```

These are my regex

```
\b\s(?!\b(\d{1,3}|\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]|\d{5,})\b)\b\S*
```

Expected output is: `of the blabla`

This regex works but it does not exclude "of" because of the (). Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: the expected output is " `of the blabla`

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the leading word boundary?

Comment: If the expected output is an array of `["of", "the", "blabla"]`, you should not use a word boundary at the start of the pattern in the first place, see `\s(?!\b(\d{1,3}|\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]|\d{5,})\b)\S*` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%28%3f!%5cb%28%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%7c%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%7c%5cd%7b5%2c%7d%29%5cb%29%5cS*&i=Section+78%281%29+of+the+blabla). Is that what you need? Please explain the rules and state if you really need an array as a result.

Comment: the expected output will be "of the blabla". The ones that you did is taking one by one of the word is it? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @lara Posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56322171/3832970).

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `.+\d\)?`

Explanation:

`.+` - match one or more times of any charaters

`\d` - match digit

`\)?` - match `)` zero or one time

Because of greediness of `+` it will match until last digit, if it's in bracket, then match following bracket.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/47WVcj/1)

Alternatively use `\d+(?:\(\d+\))?(.+)`

Then desired output is in first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/msA4si/1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you need to change is to remove the `\b` before `\S*` and replace the `\S*` with `.+` or `.*` (if the match can be an empty string).

```
\s(?!\b(?:\d{1,3}|\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]|\d{5,})\b)(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%28%3f!%5cb%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%7c%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%7c%5cd%7b5%2c%7d%29%5cb%29%28.%2b%29&i=Section+78%281%29+of+the+blabla), grab Group 1 value. Note I turned the first group matching digits in the negative lookahead into a non-capturing group to avoid clutter in the resulting match list.

[VB.NET demo](https://rextester.com/UBRU88177):

```
Dim r As New Regex("\s(?!\b(?:\d{1,3}|\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]|\d{5,})\b)(.+)")
Dim s As String
s = "Section 78(1) of the blabla"
For Each m As Match In r.Matches(s)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

Result: `of the blabla`.